# How to handle gmail login and perform action on inbox in my cypress test?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have to perform below steps in cypress test 
I have user Page-Object model, commands and env variable as well

1. Login with my app username and password
2. send an invitation to Gmail ID
3. Login into the Gmail with Gmail UN and password
4. Click on inbox and click on the first email which got the invitation from app username
5. click on the confirmation email and then its navigate to the second tab
6. login with my app

Please help me with how I can test with this scenarios in cypress test?

Comment: Can you add the code that you tried on your end to the question?

Comment: i never did that, but i saw such actions here as a possible example  https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Log-in-command-using-request